# how to allow args and kwargs while requiring one arg and kwarg; python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.x, built-in

I have a function:

```
def get_results(datasource, attribute='all_results', *args, **kwargs):
    """gets results for basic datasource format"""
    print(args, kwargs)
    ds = datasource(*args, **kwargs)
    ds.get()
    results = getattr(ds, attribute)
    return results
```

called like

```
results = get_results(ThisDataSource, 'somestringID')
```

giving args/kwargs

```
(), {}
```

It was working as

```
def get_results(datasource, *args, **kwargs):
    """gets results for basic datasource format"""
    print(args, kwargs)
    ds = datasource(*args, **kwargs)
    ds.get()
    results = ds.all_results()
    return results
```

giving args/kwargs

```
('somestringID',), {}
```

This old way is bad because the datasource may want to return rows, columns, etc
It was working as

```
results = get_results(ThisDataSource, 'somestringID')
```

which caused

```
ds = ThisDataSource('somestringID')
```

How can I give it a default in the declaration but still allow args and kwargs? 
I want to call

```
results = get_results(ThisDataSource, 'somestringID', attribute='rows')
```

and have `args = ('somestringID'), and retain access to`attribute='rows'`

Thank you

Comment: You cannot give a default value and also have the argument be part of `kwargs`.  `kwargs` is specifically for arguments whose names (let alone default values) are not specified in the argument signature.  Is that what you're asking?  Please show an example of how you want to call the function and what you want the result to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose first positional argument to be *attribute*.

```
    def get_results(datasource, *args, **kwargs):
        """gets results for basic datasource format"""
        attribute = 'all_results'  # default value
        if 'attribute' in kwargs:
            # attribure was given explicitly in keyword params
            attribute = kwargs['attribute']
        else:
            if len(args)>0:
                # args contains at least 1 value - we suppose first value to be an attribute
                # extract and remove it from args
                attribute = args.pop(0)
        print(attribute, args, kwargs)
        ...
```

Comment: this is the simplest way I just added a docstring to explain the oddity

Comment: In this case you can add one more check - that kwargs has not 'attribute' key. Pls look at modified code.

Comment: I actually mandated it be a keyword arg, just to make it clearer

Comment: Then i delete it from kwargs after setting it to attribute